# What is the best way for a brahmin man to die?

Tags: death, brahmins

As far as I know the best way in which a Kshatriya man can die is in the battlefield and it ensures he goes to heaven. (Correct me if I am wrong)

What is the best way for a brahmin man to die ?

Although the best way for anyone of any varna to die is to remember Krishna at the time of death (Gita 8:5)

> Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.

But anything specific for a brahmin man in traditional hinduism.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you believe in the 4-verna system. Today we have become a mixed society, old wisdom may not be applicable to today’s society.

You are right that for Kashtriya the best death is the death while fighting on the battlefield. Which means that you die doing your duties. To translate that for Brahmin, the best death is die while doing Bramhin’s duties or live whole life doing best Bramhin’s duties and die.

It seems that you also believe that the last moment before death is magical. Note that remembering God at the moment of death has 2 meanings. Obvious meaning is the magical meaning. But it is not logical, because, if someone has lived a bad life, he must be punished, no matter what. More practical meaning is that if someone has lived Godly life, only then it is possible that at the end moment he will remember God. So, to live a good life is the real message.